# Can I use the minimum lambda.1se among 100 iterations of 10-fold cv.glmnet to tune the final model?

Tags: machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, cross-validation, predictive-models, lasso

I am running 10-fold cross-validation(cv.glmnet) 100 times on a training dataset in R. The purpose of this process is to find the optimal lambda to tune the final model for my prediction model.

1. I did 100 rounds of 10-fold cv.glmnet

```
for (i in 1:100) {
            lasso.fit[[i]] = cv.glmnet(x = as.matrix(data), y = ref.groups, type.measure = "class", alpha = 1, family = "binomial")
            lasso.coef[[i]] = as.data.frame(as.matrix(coef(lasso.fit[[i]],s = lasso.fit[[i]]$lambda.1se)))
            lasso.lambda[[i]] = data.frame(lasso.fit[[i]]$lambda.min, lasso.fit[[i]]$lambda.1se)
            lasso.cvm[[i]]= data.frame(lasso.fit[[i]]$cvm[lasso.fit[[i]]$lambda==lasso.fit[[i]]$lambda.min],
                                       lasso.fit[[i]]$cvm[lasso.fit[[i]]$lambda==lasso.fit[[i]]$lambda.1se])}
```

2. then extract the lowest lambda.1se from 100 iterations

```
write.table(lasso.cvm, file="lasso.cvm.csv",row.names=FALSE,sep=",") ##check the lowest lambda.1se

lmabda_opt=lasso.fit[["15"]]$lambda.1se ##extract optimal lambda -> round 15 was the lowest lambda.1se among 100iterations
```

3. Final model tuning

```
lasso.fit.fin= glmnet(as.matrix(data),  y = ref.groups,alpha = 1, family = "binomial",lambda = lmabda_opt) ##manually plugging lambda into glmnet
```

This was my procedure for model development. It is known that lambda.1se gives the most regularized model, which is most simple within one standard deviation of the optimal model. So I thought it would be best to pick the model with the minimum lambda.1se of all 100 iterations. I was wondering can I use the minimum lambda.1se among 100 iterations to tune my final model for the prediction?
Thank you.